# Template is called where it should not to be

Tags: xslt

I've the below two XML cases.

Case1:

```
<para>Rent is the sum of money paid by the Tenant to the Landlord for the exclusive use of premises. The Landlord and Tenant signs a <page num="4"/>tenancy agreement which has to be stamped with the tax authorities as required under the Stamp Duties Act. The stamping of a tenancy agreement gives it validity but if the tenancy agreement is not stamped that does not mean</para>
```

Case2:

```
<para><page num="5"/>The Writ of Distress proceedings is an effective way to recover arrears in rent but regard must be had to the Landlord/Tenant relationship and the effect of publicity of such proceedings to the image of the building amongst other things.</para>
```

and the below XSLT

```
    <xsl:template match="para">
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[(self::page)]"/>
  <li class="item">
  <div class="para">
<span class="item-num">
<xsl:value-of select="../@num"></xsl:value-of>
</span>  
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::page)]"/>
  </div>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
        <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>

    <a name="{concat('pg_',./@num)}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

What I'm trying to do is check if `page` is the immediate(first) child of `para` and print that value first and then do the rest. But in both the cases, the `page` is printed first.

In the above cases provided, for case1, the `page` should be called just like any other template in `para`, since it is not the immediate child of `para`, but in case2, first the `page` has to be printed and next the template is to be called, as `page num="5"` is the immediate child of `para` Please let me know how I can do this.

A demo is [here](http://xsltransform.net/gWcDMex)

Comment: The `page` element _is_ an immediate child of the `para` in both cases.

Comment: Hi @IanRoberts, i meant, in case 1 there is come text and then page and in case 2 there is directly page as child with no text or any other node in between, i want to differentiate these two

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you mean is that you want to perform extra processing when **page** is the first child node under **para**. Your **apply-templates** need to look like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1][self::page]" />
```

However, it also sounds like you want to perform other processing on **page** elements regardless. You probably need two templates matching **page** here, but one with a "mode" to distinguish it from your normal processing.

Call it like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
```

And match it like this

```
<xsl:template match="page" mode="first">
```

This would contain the code to output your processing instruction.

For "normal" processing of the **page** element, just have another template matching **page** without the mode

```
<xsl:template match="page">
    <a name="{concat('pg_',./@num)}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
      <li class="item">
      <div class="para">
    <span class="item-num">
    <xsl:value-of select="../@num"></xsl:value-of>
    </span>  
    <xsl:apply-templates />
      </div>
      </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="page">
        <a name="{concat('pg_',./@num)}"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="page" mode="first">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
            <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: If you don't want both "page" templates to apply to apply to the first **page** element, then add the following template to ignore it

```
<xsl:template match="page[not(preceding-sibling::node())]" />
```

Note, this will only work if you have `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` present in your document, to strip out white-space only text nodes. Alternatively, you could write this

```
<xsl:template match="page[not(preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()) or normalize-space()])]" />
```

EDIT 2: The reason you need the extra templates is because of this line

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

This is will look for templates that match all the child elements under the current **para** element. So, for a **page** element, the following template will be matched

```
<xsl:template match="page">
```

But you say you don't want the very first **page** element to be matched in this case. Therefore, you are a more 'specific' template to match it. For example

```
<xsl:template match="page[not(preceding-sibling::node())]" />
```

This template matches **page** elements with no preceding siblings; i.e. the very first element under **para**.

XSLT has the concept of priority for templates. Where a template matching an element with a condition specified, that template will always be given priority. In this case, the specific template simply ignores the **page** element, to ensure it doesn't get output.

For other **page** elements, the other template will be used as normal.

Comment: Hi @TimC, this is not working as expected, here `<a name="pg_5"/>` is inside `<div class="para">`, but i don't want it to be called inside the `item` since, it is the first immediate child of `para`, i.e. there is no others text/nodes between them. and `<a name="pg_4"/>` is correct and is as expected.

Comment: @user2423959 - I have made an edit to my answer to show how you can ignore the first **page** in this instance.

Comment: thank you very much this is working like a charm, but can you please explain what is going on with these two templates, please i really can't understand. Thanks

Comment: I've made a second edit to try to explain. It is to do with template priority.

Comment: Hi @TimC, based on your suggestion, i've some xslt written, but i was stuck, can you please have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164342/match-uncaught-though-declared-in-xsl?noredirect=1#comment42826217_27164342