# match uncaught though declared in XSL

Tags: xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<para indent="no">
   <star.page>18</star.page> Further to same.
</para>
```

and when i run the below XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="para">

    <xsl:value-of select="./node()[1][self::star.page]|./label/node()[1][self::star.page]"/>
    <div>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@align">
                <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para align-</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./@align"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

When i run this, instead of printing `<div class="para">18</div>`, it is printing `<div class="para"></div>`

please let me know where am i going wrong and how can i fix this.

Thanks

Comment: In absolute terms the X-Path would be: /child::para[position=1]/child::star.page/child::text() will give 18

Comment: Hi @Ironluca, this is not working

Comment: Please run the XPath separately (not as part of XSL) and check if it returns value 18

Comment: I did try it, even there this is not caught :-(

Comment: Try this: /child::root/child::para[position()=1]/child::star.page/child::text() , where root is your document element

Comment: Hi @Ironluca, can you please have a look into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165917/apply-templates-select-substring-after. Thanks

Comment: Check the post, added xpath to comment