# apply templates select substring-after

Tags: xslt-2.0

I've the below XML line.

```
<toc-title>1.   <content-style>Short title</content-style></toc-title>
```

here i wanted to apply templates on substring-after `1.`

I tried the below XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="toc-title/text()" mode="x">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="substring-after(.,' ')" regex="([a-z]+)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="regex-group(1)" mode="x"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="x">

</xsl:template>
```

but when i run this it throws the below error.

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/FLPHK_CHAP.xsl:239: Not a node item - item has type xs:string with value 'title' -   Details: -     XTTE0520: The result of evaluating the 'select' attribute of the <xsl:apply-templates> instruction may only contain nodes
```

I'm, unable to how to do this. please help me on fixing it.

Thanks

Comment: Xpath expression: substring-after(/child::root/child::toc-title[position()=1]/child::text(),'.') , where root is your document element, '.' is the . after 1. In your case it will return the three spaces in 1.

Comment: i'm able to get the value, but unable to aply templates on that

Comment: match='/child::root/child::child::toc-title'
inside the template, <value-of select='substring-after(/child::root/child::toc-title[position()=1]/child::text(),'.') '
Should do the trick

Comment: You can't apply templates to a string, which is what `regex-group(1)` is. You could do an `xsl:call-template` to call a named template and pass `regex-group(1)` as a parameter (`xsl:with-param`). However, the way you're using `xsl:analyze-string`, with the context being `toc-title/text()`, doesn't make any sense. If you add an example of what the output should be, suggested solutions can be provided.