# Get the text based on the following sibling

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <main.line>
            <main>
                <name>Mohamad</name>
                <job.title prefix="no">B</job.title>
            </main>
            <main>
                <name>David</name>
                <job.title prefix="no">B</job.title>
            </main>
            <main>
                <name>Hashim</name>
                <job.title prefix="no">B</job.title>
            </main>
            <main>
                <name>Anthony</name>
                <job.title prefix="no">C</job.title>
            </main>
        </main.line>
```

Here i'm trying to print the name and job.title in the below way.

If the `job.title` is same and there are more than two similar occurrences, the name has to be print with a `comma` and the last name should be printed with an `and` along with the `job.title` concatenated with `A` at start.(This is a bit confusing but my output below will make this clear).

If there are two cases then it should be printed with `and` but no `comma`

If there is no such case, the name should be printed directly along with the `job.title`.

The desired output is as below.

```
Mohamad, David and Hashim BA, Anthony C
```

The XSLT I tried is as below.

```
<xsl:template match="main.line">
    <xsl:for-each select="main  ">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./job.title=following-sibling::main/job.title">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./job.title='A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./name"/>
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::main[1]/name"/>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./job.title"/>
                        <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(position() = last()) and fn:not(fn:position()=1)">
                        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=last() and fn:not(fn:position()=1)">
                        <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="job.title"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But the output that i get currently is

```
Mohamad, David BA David, Hashim BA , Hashim B and Anthony C.
```

please let me know where did i go wrong and how i can get the desired output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `for-each-group` with `group-by` (if you want to group all `main` elements with the same `job.title`) or `group-adjacent` (if you want to group only siblings with the same `job.title`), here is an example using `group-by`:

```
<xsl:template match="main.line">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="main" group-by="job.title">
    <xsl:value-of select="if (count(current-group()) eq 1)
                          then concat(name, ' ', job.title)
                          else if (count(current-group()) eq 2)
                               then concat(current-group()[1]/name, ' and ', current-group()[2]/name, job.title, 'A')
                               else concat(string-join(current-group()[position() lt (last() - 1)]/name, ', '), ', ',
                                           current-group()[last() - 1]/name, ' and ', current-group()[last()]/name, ' ', job.title, 'A')"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Marthin, this is awesome, worked like charm. Just a quick Question, if i have multiple `C`, it should be shown as `BC`, can i edit the above adding an extra `if` clause or am i supposed to use a `choose`?

Comment: It should be possible to add an `if` clause.

Comment: Hi @Martin, if you don't mind can you please have a look at this post and help me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164342/match-uncaught-though-declared-in-xsl?noredirect=1#comment42826217_27164342. Thanks